# Simple script for importing csv, modifying columns and writing back in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am working on a project and I have a large csv doc in Excel that I'd like to modify with python so that I can correctly run it through a statistical analysis program. I am learning python as my first language and know enough to be dangerous but I'm getting flustered with piecing together code from several sources. Right now I have the import down:

```
import csv

with open("file_path.csv", 'r') as file:
     reader = csv.reader(file)
     file_list = list(reader)

print(file_list)
```

What I need to do is go from this:

```
['person_id', 'person_name', 'sex', 'blood_pressure_type',       'blood_pressure_value'], ['1', 'Fred', 'M', 'systolic', '160'], ['1', 'Fred', 'M', 'diastolic', '80'], ['2', 'Linda', 'F', 'systolic', '155'], ['2', 'Linda', 'F', 'diastolic', '78']
```

to this:

```
['person_id', 'person_name', 'sex', 'blood_pressure_type', 'blood_pressure_value', 'blood_pressure_type', 'blood_pressure_value'], ['1', 'Fred', 'M', 'systolic', '160', 'diastolic', '80'], ['2', 'Linda', 'F', 'systolic', '155','diastolic', '78']
```

such that the tuples aren't repeating for the same person and both systolic and diastolic blood pressures are in a single tuple for each person while maintaining a separated attribute column.

After this, I'd like to write back to the csv file with the new tuples overwriting the old, or simply creating a new one if that's easier. Can anyone help with a import/modify/export for python 3.x? I'm most appreciative for any help, even partial.

P.S. Like I said I'm a newbie and I've read that python 2.7 has a lot to offer. If I should be using something other than 3.x for this I'd love to hear opinions.

Answer (score 0):

If the input file is sorted by `person_id`, then you could just read the rows in pairs and merge them into a single row:

```
rows = ['person_id', 'person_name', 'sex', 'blood_pressure_type',
        'blood_pressure_value', 'blood_pressure_type', 'blood_pressure_value']

for first, second in zip(file_list[::2], file_list[1::2]):
    row = first + second[3:]
    rows.append(row)
```

Then [write](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.writer) `rows` into a new CSV file.

**Update**: you can use a similar approach to process multiple pairs that go together. Just split the list of rows into two by the value of `'blood_pressure_type'`, then `zip()` and merge them:

```
systolic = []
diastolic = []
for row in file_list:
    if row[-2] == 'systolic':
        systolic.append(row)
    else:
        diastolic.append(row)    

for first, second in zip(systolic, diastolic):
    row = first + second[3:]
    rows.append(row)
```

Comment: Just note that this assumes the input file to be ordered - oterwise a more complex agregation by "id" would be needed

Comment: Also, as te OP is new to Python, explaining what it does would be welcome.

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. This is exactly the direction I need to go. One follow-up question. If I have multiple pairs of tuples that go together, for example sometimes a person will have 3 readings (systolic, systolic, systolic, diastolic, diastolic, diastolic) with 0-3, 1-4, and 2-5 being the pairs and sometimes only one, sometimes 10 just based on the person and how many times they visited. They will all have the same person_id and are always in that same order with variable counts. Is there an adjustment that can be made to account for an unknown number of readings?

Comment: ^^Also wouldn't mind a comment or two so I can follow the logic. I really appreciate the help nonetheless. I'm diving in head first but it sort of feels like drinking from a fire hose.

Comment: @eugene_y thanks for the update. I'm giving both your method and the dictionary method above a try. Doing a bit of the transforming and will update asap.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [`DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) and [`DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for things like this.

`DictReader()` operates like a regular reader but maps the information read into a dict. So the fieldnames are keys to the dictionary. eg:

```
for row in reader:
    row['fieldname'] = data
```

I think this would be easily achievable by using a dictionary and storing the information to write:

```
import csv
import os
from collections import defaultdict

# create a dictionary to store user information in
info_dict = defaultdict(list)
file_data = csv.DictReader(open(os.path.join(pathname, filename)).readlines())
for info in file_data:
     # if you have already added info into the dictionary for that id, just add the new information (blood_pressure_type and blood_pressure_value)
     if not info['person_id'] in info_dict:
         info_dict[info['person_id']].extend(info['person_name'], info['sex'], info['blood_pressure_type'], info['blood_pressure_value'])
     else:
             info_dict[info['person_id']].extend(info['blood_pressure_type'], info['blood_pressure_value'])
    
# now you have a dictionary that looks like 
# { person_id: [ person_name, sex, blood_pressure_type, blood_pressure_value, blood_pressure_type, blood_pressure_value ] }

with open("file_write_path.csv", 'w') as file_write:
    # declare the fieldnames for the top row of the csv
    # it doesn't have to be blood_pressure_...1/2
    fieldnames = ['person_id', 'person_name', 'sex', 'blood_pressure_type1', 'blood_pressure_value1', 'blood_pressure_type2', 'blood_pressure_value2']
    # make a writer and pass the headers as the fieldnames for the csv writer.
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_write, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
    # write the headers
    writer.writeheader()
    
    # iterate through your info dictionary, you have a list of the information you want for the person_id that you have, so write each row with that info.
    for person_id, info in info_dict.items():
         writer.writerow({ fieldnames[0]: person_id, fieldnames[1]: info[0], fieldnames[2]: info[1], fieldnames[3]: info[2], fieldnames[4]: info[3], fieldnames[5]: info[4], fieldnames[6]: info[5] })
```

If this doesn't make sense, I can clarify any of it!

## Update: I fixed the opening for `DictReader`

You could alternatively do the same thing like: `file_data = csv.DictReader(file.readlines())` and use the way of `with open(filename, 'r') as file:`

Comment: Hi @cole, thanks for this answer! I did some of the switching around to make it work and got this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jeremyprovance/Downloads/dict_csv_reader_writer.py", line     7, in <module>
        file_data = csv.DictReader(file).readlines()
    AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: Oops, my mistake! I updated it, what I did to fix it was put `readlines()` where I meant for it to go in the first place, on the file! This way of declaring the `DictReader()` will also allow you not to have to put `with open(blah, blah) as blah:` to open the file! Now all you need to do is put the file's parent directory where I have `pathname` and the csv's name where I have `filename` @JeremyProvance